# unix script to check file size of previos day and trigger mail if not matching with todays file size

Tags: unix

I need a help to write a script for below scenario

Need to compare the file size of previous day and current day if current file size drops less than 20%  of previous day or if current file size is 0 then i should trigger a mail , how can we do this in Unix script ?

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 599076 599076  3371531 Dec  1 08:15 engine.log
-rw-r-----+ 1 599076 599076    86949 Dec  2 08:16 engine.log
```

Comment: You can get file size and assign to variable with `previous=$(stat -c %s engine.log)`. Now compare `previous` with `current` to test if they match.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch file name and then use (du -m) command for the size and then put your logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Run this once a day:

```
set -- `ls -l engine.log`
LIMIT=`expr $5 \* 5`
read <yestersize && [ $LIMIT -lt $REPLY -o $5 -eq 0 ] && mail ...
echo $5 >yestersize
```